# MongoDB how to group, get the biggest with dynamic ranking field

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have data like this:

```
{
  "_id": "n383hopmfz69j7rdbh1ny56g",
  "playerId": "402ddb96-0edf-4df7-9ba8-ffb201ef6a70",
  "playedChartId": "3w2aaz0ryd58it6r3w0klu5r",
  "score": 966858
},
{
  "_id": "5e83ecd30102b60ea4a11fe9",
  "playerId": "402ddb96-0edf-4df7-9ba8-ffb201ef6a70", // the same player
  "playedChartId": "3w2aaz0ryd58it6r3w0klu5r",
  "score": 954201 // with lower score
},
{
  "_id": "629da76873dff6547eb1e9b3",
  "playerId": "f6fe9c4d-98e6-450a-937c-d64848eacc40", // the different player
  "playedChartId": "3w2aaz0ryd58it6r3w0klu5r", // the same chart
  "score": 902238
}
```

As I know how to filter 'playedChartId', so I ignored the other documents with different 'playedChartId'.

Then I want to group them by 'playerId', find the document with the best 'score', with 'ranking'.

The result I wanted:

```
[
  {
    // the original document
    "_id": "n383hopmfz69j7rdbh1ny56g",
    "playerId": "402ddb96-0edf-4df7-9ba8-ffb201ef6a70",
    "playedChartId": "3w2aaz0ryd58it6r3w0klu5r",
    "score": 966858,

    // the generated ranking value
    "ranking": 1
  },
  {
    "_id": "n383hopmfz69j7rdbh1ny56g",
    "playerId": "f6fe9c4d-98e6-450a-937c-d64848eacc40", // the different player
    "playedChartId": "3w2aaz0ryd58it6r3w0klu5r", // the same chart
    "score": 902238,

    "ranking": 2
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `$sort` - Order by `playerId` then by `score` descending.
2. `$group` - Group by `playerId`, and take the first document as `data` via `$first`.
3. `$replaceWith` - Replace input document with `data`.
4. `$setWindowFields` - Perform ranking via [`$rank`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/rank/) order by `score` descending.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $sort: {
      playerId: 1,
      score: -1
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$playerId",
      data: {
        $first: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceWith: "$data"
  },
  {
    $setWindowFields: {
      sortBy: {
        score: -1
      },
      output: {
        ranking: {
          $rank: {}
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/qGCs1dvI34V)